# New validation rule not working fully

Tags: validation-rule

i have created a new validation rule which should prevent saves to a dunning action record if the type is email and either email body OR email subject is null.

Currently i have:

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(Dunning_Action_Type__c, "Email"), 
    OR( 
        ISBLANK( Email_Body__c ),
        ISBLANK( Email_Subject__c ) 
    )
)
```

But i am still able to save with type = email and body null if subject is populated.

Comment: What is the data type of Email body ?

Comment: it is a rich text area (32768)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Email body is a rich text field, you will always get false when you use  ISBLANK or ISNULL in a validation rule.

You will have to use LEN function in validation rule to check if it is null.

Below validation rule should work for you

```
AND( 
    ISPICKVAL(Dunning_Action_Type__c, "Email"), 
    OR( 
        LEN( Email_Body__c )= 0,
        ISBLANK( Email_Subject__c ) 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: If you always get true then the validation would always prevent save. Did you mean isblank and isnull on rich text always returns false?

Comment: Thanks @Eric for pointing that out. Corrected it in the answer.